# Change jQuery/Bootstrap tab with link/click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a hard time trying to get the tab to change from tab 1 to tab 2. I've found a few topics on stackoverflow but none of them worked so I've setup a html/jquery/css page here:

http://ksm.fm/misc/tab-test/

Any ideas how to have the tab change to "Tab 2" when the link is clicked? Im using bootstrap which is confusing me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voawtzt2/) for this, easier to play around with:

but if you change your link to this it works:

```
<a href="#" onclick='$(".nav-tabs a[href=\"#B\"]").tab("show")'>Link to tab 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this a little piece of javascript/jquery code

```
//Force click method.
//You can directly put the force click method in the click event handler
//But I prefer this way for readability and ease of maintenance.
function toggleClick(elementSelector) {
    $(elementSelector).click();
}
//Delegated click event on the tab-content section
//This event will handle all Anchor tags within tab content
//All you have to do with the markup is add a data-id on the tabs i.e **li > a** which is located in the UL tag
$(".tab-content").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.tagName === "A") {
        toggleClick("[data-id='" + e.target.hash + "']");
        //Without toggleClick method
        //$("[data-id='" + e.target.hash + "']").click();
    }
});
```

I also created a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iam_nash/87qn20an/) for you to work around.